# Array Search by first character

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any way to search the javascript array which has the element which starts with the particular char **without looping the array**.

Example:

```
   var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

From this array I want to check any element starts with the character 'M'.
Note: Should not loop the array.

Comment: There is no way. Need use loop..

Comment: @java-seekar do not bring homework here

Comment: @Java-Seekar in real project no one is restricting you from using loop. no one will say in my project  you can not use loop

Comment: @Java-Seekar is somebody restrict you from using loop in this case ??if yes ask them for a solution , and provide as an answer to your question , we are also curious about the solution that does not use a loop

Comment: I posted a solution and a possible reason for not using a loop. But, I wouldnt do it with javascript if that was the case. I would most definately implement some type of database storage(be it serverside and ajax or the browser database storage object)

Answer (score 3):

you can use [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function, but internally it still will use loop. In fact there is no way of how to check the full array without loop.

```
fruits.filter(function(item) { return item.substring(0, 1) == 'M'; });
```

Comment: 1 for pointing the reality behind filter, i mean it also use loop

Answer (score 1):

If the array does not contains objects or the values does not contains `,` then use can join the array to create a string then use a regex

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var exists = /,M/.test(fruits.join());
console.log(exists)
```

Comment: But i guess `join()` uses a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do that is by making them a subpart of an associative array which defines the indexes.

So the moment you initialise/load up the array you define which characters are in there.
This way you will only have to loop at the init or load functions of your values

```
mainIndex = new Array();
while(loadingarray.hasNext()) {
    var next = loadingarray.getNext();
    var indexchar = next.charAt(0);
    if(typeof mainIndex[indexchar] == 'undefined') {
        mainIndex[indexchar] = new Array();
    }
mainIndex[indexchar].push(next);
}
```

Comment: Indeed - a hash table is the only way that the (rather ambiguous) requirements of this question could be met.

Comment: sometimes a hashtable is the way to store things. We of course don't know how big the array is op has. There might a performance issue with 2 million items array. We don't know. but thats the only reason I can guess he doesnt want to loop. Maybe access millions of customer data in an array, and then finding that one customer :P Still, it all has to be loaded up so there is at least one looping level... but hey, memory is cheap :P

Comment: I actually think the question is probably homework spawned - but an interesting one nonetheless. It's true a hash table doesn't guarantee a lack of looping in the case of collisions.

Comment: Looking at op's other questions he might be a level above homework. Still, database storage using the browsers internal database object might be better for this question then to let it reside in memory. That way it is persistent and doesnt have to be loaded up every time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the iterative method filter() like this:

```
var match = fruits.filter(function (item, index, array) {
    return item.charAt(0) === "M";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/tydrgmoa/

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
var exists = fruits.some(function(element){return element[0] === "M"});
```

More info on `.some()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var match = fruits.filter(function (item, index, array) {
    if(item.charAt(0) === "M")
         console.log(item);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a02z99xg/4/

Answer (score -1):

No built in function , create custom function.

Comment: can you create a custom function for doing the same ?